# Power BI calculating time difference excluding weekends and non working hours

Tags: powerbi

I have the below table and calculating the durations between **First_change_Date** and **Create_date** using this DAX formula:

```
Response_time = 
    VAR Minutes = DATEDIFF('otrs ticket Response'[otrs ticket.create_time], 'otrs ticket Response'[First_Change_time],MINUTE)
    var days =INT(Minutes/1440)
    var hourNo=INT(MOD(Minutes,1440) / 60)
    var minuteNO=MOD(Minutes,60)
RETURN
    CONCATENATE( CONCATENATE( CONCATENATE(days,"d "), CONCATENATE(hourNo, "H ")), CONCATENATE(minuteNO, "m "))
```

I want to exclude the weekends (Friday, Saturday in my case) and non working hours (5:00pm - 9:00am)

Data:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my client, I have created a logic. First created a `WorkingHoursTable`.

[image]

Then created a calculated column with the following formula, in the table which has the start and end dateTime's.

```
Working Hours Between Dates = 
var startDate = [yourStartDateTime].[Date]
var startTime = [yourStartDateTime] - startDate
var endDate = [yourEndDateTime].[Date]
var endTime = [yourEndDateTime] - endDate

var firstFullDay = startDate + 1
var lastFullDay = endDate - 1

var inBetweenWorkingHours = 
    IF(
        firstFullDay > lastFullDay,
        0,
        SUMX(CALENDAR(firstFullDay, lastFullDay), LOOKUPVALUE(WorkingHoursTable[WorkingHoursInAllDay], WorkingHoursTable[WeekDay], WEEKDAY([Date], 2)))
    )

var firstDayStart = LOOKUPVALUE(WorkingHoursTable[StartTime], WorkingHoursTable[WeekDay], WEEKDAY(startDate, 2))
var firstDayEnd = LOOKUPVALUE(WorkingHoursTable[EndTime], WorkingHoursTable[WeekDay], WEEKDAY(startDate, 2))

var lastDayStart = LOOKUPVALUE(WorkingHoursTable[StartTime], WorkingHoursTable[WeekDay], WEEKDAY(endDate, 2))
var lastDayEnd = LOOKUPVALUE(WorkingHoursTable[EndTime], WorkingHoursTable[WeekDay], WEEKDAY(endDate, 2))

var effectiveStartTime = IF(startTime < firstDayStart, firstDayStart, startTime)
var effectiveEndTime = IF(endTime > lastDayEnd, lastDayEnd, endTime)
        
return 
    IF(
        startDate = endDate,
        24 * IF(effectiveEndTime > effectiveStartTime, effectiveEndTime - effectiveStartTime, 0),
        var firstDayWorkingHour = 
            24 *
            IF(
                startTime > firstDayEnd,
                0,
                firstDayEnd - effectiveStartTime
            )

        var lastDayWorkingHour = 
            24 *
            IF(
                endTime < lastDayStart,
                0,
                effectiveEndTime - lastDayStart
            )
        
        return firstDayWorkingHour + lastDayWorkingHour + inBetweenWorkingHours
    )
```

In this formula you just set the first 4 variables correctly. Then it will calculate total working hours. Unit will be in hours.

Edit: As I see from your post that your weekends are Friday and Saturday, you will need to use WEEKDAY functions slightly different. You can send 1 as a second parameter to WEEKDAY function, instead of 2. You will also need to modify the `WeekDay` column of `WorkingHoursTable`.

After this one, you can parse it to '9d 20H 52m' with your formula.

Comment: To be honest, the solution seems great. Now, I am trying to modify it to match with my data and see. but what is it really meant by ".[Date]" in the first 4 parameters?

Comment: Also in the ```WorkingHoursTable``` which exact day you are starting with? I mean what is the day for ```WeekDay``` 1?

Comment: @OmarAlSaghier For me Weekday 1 is Monday. You can create a table with Weekday 1 = Sunday. Just be sure to use WEEKDAY function correctly. Its second parameter asks for the start day of the week.

Comment: @OmarAlSaghier If your datetime field is has the date hierarchy, [Date] will give the date part of the dateTime value, ignoring the time part. Don't get confused with [Date] part. Just be sure to set startDate and endDate with only dates without times. Set startTime and endTime with only time parts.

Comment: Now I think I am moving on .. but I am having an error with SUMX ```SUMX(CALENDAR(firstFullDay, lastFullDay), LOOKUPVALUE('WorkingDaysTimes'[Total working hours], 'WorkingDaysTimes'[WeekDay], WEEKDAY([Date], 1)))``` and the error is ```The function SUMX cannot work with values of type String``` .. Do you know what the error is ?

Comment: @OmarAlSaghier Check the type of WorkingDaysTimes'[Total working hours] column. Ensure it is decimal.

Comment: I think I have almost done it. but sometimes it automatically adds 8 hours to the answer. I think it is because I did enter the working hours during days (5, 6) (Friday, Saturday) as: 00:00:00 to 00:00:00 .. Do you think that's correct?

Comment: I have worked hard on your solution, and it worked fine on a huge amount of data, but still it has some not correct results but I don't know why. I will still accept your solution as it helped so much so far. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @OmarAlSaghier In your previous comment, you said that you used `WEEKDAY([Date], 1)` as WEEKDAY function. This means you are assuming 1st day of the week as Sunday. To be consistent with this approach Friday and Saturday are being 6 and 7, respectively. In your comment it is stated that they are (5, 6). For weekends, 00:00-00:00 makes sense to me. However, I didn't have that challenge, so not hundred percent sure.

Comment: You are the best man. you soled a huge issue for me. It is working perfectly now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I split the date/time in to date and time columns. I then use a date dimension, where one of the columns is "Is `Working Day" = TRUE()`, based on which day of the week it is (a simple calculated column). In the time dimension, you do the same to identify `"Working Hour" = TRUE()`, again, a simple calculation.

Once you have the dimensions in place it then becomes very easy to build your calculations to include / exclude.

Comment: I think as you mentioned separating Data/time into two columns date and time are the best approach. This video shows that for days, and it worked: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2ic432NvhY .... I only need to combine it with the hours and minutes left.