# How can I calculate cycle times in Power BI using DAX, excluding non-business hours?

Tags: time, powerbi, dax

How to Use DAX to calculate minutes within business hours/days

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABfJt.png)
Hello! I'm trying to figure out a problem where the Excel sheet that I loaded into Power Bi is kind of wonky and I need to calculate the cycle times between 'Assigned' and 'Completed' for each ID. The only issue is that I don't want to include the minutes outside of the business hours of 8 AM to 5 PM Monday through Friday while also excluding holidays. Below is a DAX code I used that calculates the Cycle time between the two rows found in the table I attached as a photo.
`Cycle Time =  VAR AssignedDateTime = CALCULATE( MIN('Flat File Records'[Date]), 'Flat File Records'[cr3d5_status] = "Assigned" ) & " " & CALCULATE( MIN('Flat File Records'[Time]), 'Flat File Records'[cr3d5_status] = "Assigned" ) VAR CompletedDateTime = CALCULATE( MAX('Flat File Records'[Date]), 'Flat File Records'[cr3d5_status] = "Completed" ) & " " & CALCULATE( MAX('Flat File Records'[Time]), 'Flat File Records'[cr3d5_status] = "Completed" ) RETURN IF( ISBLANK(AssignedDateTime) || ISBLANK(CompletedDateTime), BLANK(), DATEDIFF(AssignedDateTime, CompletedDateTime, MINUTE) )`

I am having trouble with not also counting the minutes outside of the business hours. Below will be an example of code I tried to create to exclude those hours and days:

`Cycle Time (Business Hours) =  VAR AssignedDateTime = CALCULATE( MINX( FILTER('Flat File Records', 'Flat File Records'[cr3d5_status] = "Assigned"), VALUE('Flat File Records'[Date]) + TIMEVALUE('Flat File Records'[Time]) ) ) VAR CompletedDateTime = CALCULATE( MAXX( FILTER('Flat File Records', 'Flat File Records'[cr3d5_status] = "Completed"), VALUE('Flat File Records'[Date]) + TIMEVALUE('Flat File Records'[Time]) ) ) VAR BusinessStartTime = TIME(8, 0, 0) VAR BusinessEndTime = TIME(17, 0, 0) VAR StartDateTimeAdjusted = IF( AssignedDateTime < DATEVALUE(AssignedDateTime) + BusinessStartTime, DATEVALUE(AssignedDateTime) + BusinessStartTime, AssignedDateTime ) VAR EndDateTimeAdjusted = IF( CompletedDateTime > DATEVALUE(CompletedDateTime) + BusinessEndTime, DATEVALUE(CompletedDateTime) + BusinessEndTime, CompletedDateTime ) VAR TotalMinutes = IF( ISBLANK(AssignedDateTime) || ISBLANK(CompletedDateTime), BLANK(), DATEDIFF(StartDateTimeAdjusted, EndDateTimeAdjusted, MINUTE) ) VAR MinutesOutsideBusinessHours = IF( HOUR(AssignedDateTime) < HOUR(BusinessStartTime), (HOUR(BusinessStartTime) - HOUR(AssignedDateTime)) - 2 * 60 + MINUTE(BusinessStartTime), IF( HOUR(AssignedDateTime) > HOUR(BusinessEndTime), (HOUR(AssignedDateTime) - HOUR(BusinessEndTime)) - 2 * 60 + MINUTE(BusinessEndTime), 0 ) ) RETURN TotalMinutes`

Is there a way to do what I was attempting to do?

Comment: For inspiration:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351924/power-bi-calculating-time-difference-excluding-weekends-and-non-working-hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351924/power-bi-calculating-time-difference-excluding-weekends-and-non-working-hours) … this should be handy: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/networkdays-dax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/networkdays-dax)

Answer (score 0):

This article seems to cover it pretty well -
https://exceleratorbi.com.au/calculating-elapses-business-hours-using-dax-part-2/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Nice article. It should work the same way with # of full NETWORKDAYS () x business hrs per day + ( ‘Time of day of Complete’ - ‘Time of day of Assigned’). The advantage would be to be able to use an explicit calendar to consider the holidays.  (In case ‘Time of day of Complete’ exceeding the max daily biz hrs is not wanted, one can cut it with MIN accordingly)

Comment: Oh, I'd *absolutely* use a Calendar dimension table. Then you can just filter out non-work days. Then the only part left is to determine the "remainder" hours.

Comment: Sorry, I meant with NETWORKDAYS you can list the holidays explicitly, which make it easier to maintain. Then for remainder hrs just calculate the time difference between End and Start (without considering the date). Actually, NETWORKDAYS should also be faster, as you don’t calculate the ‘detailed hrs’ difference for each day in the period but just once (+  NETWORKDAYS x daily biz hrs)

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the discussion, this is my proposal:

- Use NETWORKDAYS() to calculate between Assigned and Completed with consideration to the weekend and holidays minus 1 (as NETWORKDAYS counts inclusively)
- times daily biz hours
- plus the time difference between Completed and Assigned (only the time component)